# Insert one row for each element in array in one query

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an array with multiple elements. The size of the array isn't always the same.

At the moment the only way I can think of doing is using a `foreach` loop and querying the database once for every element in the array.

What I am looking for a way to insert one row for one element in the array but all in one query. I would like to do is using codeigniter's active record class so that I wouldn't have to write code to check for malicious data and such.

Comment: You mean like a batch insert?  You can call insert multiple times in a single operation.  Otherwise you are talking about the design of your back-end.  For that might help to have a better idea of what this data looks like.

Comment: If you is use MySQL you can use `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: I've voted to reopen as the question is quite clear to me, I genuinely don't understand how it would be perceived as "not a real question". Perhaps it is a duplicate, but I was unable to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `insert_batch` if you just want one query:

```
$data = array();

// Sample data
$items = array('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3');

foreach ($items as $value)
{
    $data[] = array(
        'your_column_name'  =>  $value,

        // Populate more columns here if you need to
        'date_created'      =>  time()
    );
}

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

All values are escaped automatically.

Docs: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert

Answer (score 0):

You could have `$sql .= 'SQL HERE; '` so you have multiple queries in one variable, then only have one function call to run the queries.